# Can't connect to a repository in ODI (Oracle Data Integrator)

Tags: oracle, repository, oracle-data-integrator

I installed ODI and when I clicked on "Connect to repository" it gives me a screen to enter details. The first time I opened it I think I clicked on the plus and it opened another window with some info to enter. I closed it and every next time I try to do the same, it won't let me get to that screen; plus button and the pen button don't do anything when i click them and the fields are not editable.
[connecting to a repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnhSQ.png)

I tried closing and opening ODI a few times, nothing worked. Tried running it as an administrator, nothing. Ended the task in task manager, nothing. This looks like a bug to me.